# How'll the offset in these two cases be applied?

Tags: assembly, offset, twos-complement, negative-number

First of all I'm familiar with the concept of how negative numbers are presented by two's complement system and I know that when there's a jump instruction(short or near) the offset it contains will always be added to EIP register and there isn't a case where the offset is subtracted from EIP register(if I'm right!). but I wonder if in case of two following kinds of addressing with a negative presented offset, it'll be the same as the case of how the offset in a jump instruction is used that is always being added to the base and not subtracted in any case?

**(in GASM format):**
"base_address(offset,index register,scale)" like:

```
%eax(-4,%ebx,1)
```

"offset(base register)" like:

```
-4(%eax)
```

will a binary number be added to eax register or subtracted?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715521/would-there-be-such-case-of-jumping-if-yes-how

Comment: what does it have to do with that question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-4 will be added to the value of the register, decreasing it by 4. Offsets are always added.